# Why MoveToElement no response

Tags: appium, winappdriver, appium-desktop

I try to move mouse to element by moveToElement, but it doesn't work.

The code is as follows

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element);
action.Perform();
```

I think the element is found, because `element.Click()` is work

P.S. Testing program is a win32 program in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Perform action is not worked for me too. I found the way with custom method. That my example in Python.

```
def scroll_to_element(self, locator: str, timeout=2):
    by = get_locator_by_string(locator)

    def elem_none():
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self._driver, timeout).until(
                ex_cond.invisibility_of_element_located(by), ' : '.join(by))
            return True

        except TimeoutException:
            return False

    for _ in range(10):
        if elem_none() is True:

            size = self._driver.get_window_size()
            startx, starty = int(size['width']) * 0.5, int(size['height']) * 0.8
            endx, endy = int(size['width']) * 0.5, int(size['height']) * 0.2
            self._driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 1000)

            if elem_none() is False:
                break
            else:
                continue
```

My method is swiping 10 times. You can changed it to `while` but it is a bad way - test won't be ended if element won't be found.
This way works for me all times and it is enough for me. Hope it will be helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try.